# Unity5 Camera Clear flags not working properly on Gear VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, gear-vr

I'm trying to make a very simple thing that is working great in Unity but not behaving has expected in the Gear VR. 
I'm using Unity 5.4.1p4 and Oculus utilities &Plugin 1.8.

I have two OVRCameraRigs prefabs in my scene. The first prefab is rendering the "Camera1" layer only and the second prefab is set up to render the "Camera2" layer. The first prefab cameras have the Clear Flags set to Solid Color and a Depth of 0. The second prefab cameras are set to Don't Clear and have a Depth of 1.

I have 3 cubes in this scene: ForeGround, Middle and BackGround. Middle is on the "Camera1" layer while ForeGround & BackGround are on "Camera2" layer.

Here is the result in Unity (working has expected, I can see the 3 cubes) :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGntr.png

And here is the result in the Gear VR ( ForeGround & BackGround are rendered on top of the Middle cube) :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlbrL.png

Am I doing anything wrong or is it a known bug? Because I can't find anything about it and don't know how to fix that.
Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Check state cameras components in prefabs (Enable/Disable) and active them, then try set Clear Flags on all cameras components to Depth Only and check the result.